# Urgent Flag of TCP, Computer Networks

Tags: computer-networks, tcp

The **Urgent Flag(URG)** is set whenever the sender's **Application Layer** wants to send some urgent data to the receiver. In this case, the **Transport Layer** does not wait for enough data to achieve maximum segment size. Now, my question is **how do the routers in between recognize that the packet needs to be forwarded urgently**(they do not have the transport layer)?

Comment: I'm not even confident this would be [on-topic over at NetworkEngineering@SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: This was asked at an interview for recruitment for the post of a scientist at one country's most prestigious organization. Though it may have been a tricky one to check the confidence level.

Answer (score 1):

They don't.  The urgent flag doesn't affect the handling of the packet by routers.  The urgent flag is an instruction to the TCP stack on the destination host, not an instruction to routers along the path.